Ways to improve the rendering speed of uiOutputs in R Shiny
I read in the book Mastering Shiny that:

If you run this code yourself, you’ll notice that it takes a fraction of a second to appear after the app loads. That’s because it’s reactive: the app must load, trigger a reactive event, which calls the server function, yielding HTML to insert into the page. This is one of the downsides of renderUI(); relying on it too much can create a laggy UI. For good performance, strive to keep fixed as much of the user interface as possible, using the techniques described earlier in the chapter.

Due to business requirements, uiOutput's is preferred over a fixed layout. I have built a sample app, and as Hadley mentioned above, I have experienced some lag as expected.
I am wondering if there are ways to retain the dynamic UI mechanism and, if not eliminate the lag, at least reduce it so that it is less noticeable.
I understand that I may need to learn other languages, such as JavaScript, and I am happy and committed to doing so. However, it would be great to understand the available options before investing too much time without a clear goal.
Here is an example that illustrates the problem:
library(shiny)

app_start <- Sys.time()
app_start_to_first_flushed <- reactiveVal()

n_sliders <- 50L

slider_input_ids <- paste0("slider_in_", seq_len(n_sliders))
slider_output_ids <- paste0("slider_out_", seq_len(n_sliders))

ui <- fluidPage(tags$b(
  tagAppendAttributes(textOutput("time_difference"), style = "margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;")
),
lapply(slider_output_ids, uiOutput))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onFlushed(
    fun = function() {
      app_start_to_first_flushed(round(difftime(Sys.time(), app_start, units = "secs"), digits = 3L))
    }
  )
  
  output$time_difference <- renderText({
    paste("App start to first flushed event:",
          app_start_to_first_flushed(),
          "seconds")
  })
  
  mapply(function(slider_output_id, slider_input_id) {
    output[[slider_output_id]] <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(
        inputId = slider_input_id,
        label = slider_input_id,
        min = 1L,
        max = 10L,
        value = 1L
      )
    })
  }, slider_output_ids, slider_input_ids, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


It's going to be very hard for anyone to help without some example code to work with.

Thank you for your comment, I’m not seeking to a solution to improve the code but the direction to work on.

In general I'd recommend starting with fixed UI elements and e.g. hide / show them via conditionalPanel's or hidden tabsetPanel's and use their according update* (e.g. updateSelectizeInput) or proxy (e.g. dataTableProxy) functions instead of renderUI as updating already existing elements is faster then re-rendering them.

Explore other design options: for example, you might be able to use tabSets to reduce the need for renderUI calls.  Widgets on tabs other than the active one are suspended by default and therefore do not consume resources.  Also look to optimise your data dependencies - separate derivation from display.  That may allow you to use the same object as the source data for many output widgets.  If you have one or more derivations that take a noticeable time to obtain, consider using ExtendedTask.  That will allow the UI to display/update before all derivations are complete.

Furthermore, you might want to check bindCache().

@Limey, Jan and TylerH since when is performance opinion-based?
